# Java decompile->recompile process, is it safe?

Tags: java, compilation, decompiling

I know that if I take some sourcecode, compile it and decompile it, the original and final sourcecode are not the same due to the possibility of saying the same thing in different ways (e.g. `while` vs `for` loop). In other words, the process is, in a way, many-to-one, which means it is not invertible

My question is in the other direction. If I take bytecode, decompile it and then recompile it with the exact same compiler that was originally used, will the original and final bytecode be the same byte-by-byte (ignoring timestamps and non-execution metadata)? If not equal byte-by-byte, is it at least logically equivalent or there can be logical bugs introduced by the process?

I don't have the tools but I could answer my own first question (byte-by-byte equality) but not the second one (logical equivalence) hence why I'm asking for people's experience here.

Comment: It also depends on the decompiler you use. Decompiling is not documented in a JSR and is not subject to any "contract". There is not even a guarantee that a decompiler will be correct.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like there is no way for a decompiler to output 100% accurate re-compilable code for the following reasons:

- Compilation (such as decompilation) is not designed to be a bijective operation.
- There is no way for the decompiler to guess which compiler was used and with what options in order to generate the .class file.
- Decompilation does not have to respect a contract or specification like in a JSR, and it is not guaranteed that it will give a valid, repeatable or certified result.

Comment: do you have a concrete example of something that would not re-compile to the original bytecode? i know there is no JSR to decompile, but it is still a very deterministic process. And about your point #2, assume that is left to the human. In reality, the build is handled by maven, so as long as the pom is the same, you *can* guarantee the same compilation setup/context